# psql not restoring the database dump

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to restore the database. but database not restoring the sql dump. I am running following command. My sql dump have tables and copy statements.

`psql -X -h localhost -d <database> -f dump.sql`

I also tried in `psql interactively`

Edit: Removed the `;` suggested by `a_horse_with_no_name`.

```
\connect mydatabase
\i dump.sql
```

it runs with no errors. But its not creating any database tables. Any idea? Thanks

**Edit 2: There is no any error in log files.**

Comment: It is really strange. Do you see some errors in PostgreSQL log? What is your client_min_messages? You can try use psql interactively and \i dump.sql for import. Recheck dump.sql for valid content.

Comment: @PavelStehule logs added in the question. Thanks

Comment: Did you dump the db using psql from command line or via pgadmin GUI?
This may seem illogical question but I'd similar problem where dumps created by pgadmin could not be imported by using psql from command line and vice versa. I didn't have time to solve the "mystery" but I think it could be encoding issue. You may give it a try.

Comment: Looking at the log, it seems like the database already exists, and is currently in use by other sessions.

Comment: @wildplasser I re-created the database and try to import database. Now log file is empty. But database is not there.

Comment: How do you know? what does `psql -l` show you?

Comment: @wildplasser `psql -l` showing the database. and its empty. not table in it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it ran with no errors, it's very possible that the dump was imported, but the tables aren't in the public schema, so you aren't seeing them when you enter `\dt`. Check if the tables are there using these commands:

```
\dt .*.
```

Or write a select statement like the one below explicitly mentioning the database name:

```
SELECT * FROM <database_name>.<table_name>;
```

Otherwise, the only tables that are displayed are those that are in the public schema

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the file in. The drop and create statements are optional, just to be sure

```
dropdb <database>
createdb <database>
psql <database> < dump.sql
```